# Reference for Central Limit and Berry-Esseen theorems

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, central-limit-theorem

My background is mostly related to analysis, but I've recently run into a problem for which the central limit theorem naturally arises.  I find that I need to understand the delicate issues like rate of convergence, *a la* the Berry-Esseen theorem, but my background in probability is insufficient to understand the language in which such theorems are formulated.  To remedy this, I want to get a book to teach myself probability.

**I would like recommendations for probability books which satisfy the following:**

1. Fully rigorous.
2. Good description of the central limit theorem, Berry-Esseen theorem, and related rate-of-convergence issues.
3. Preferably concise, but clear and well written.  (I am familiar with measure theory, etc.)

Comment: See chapter 3.11 in Shiryaev's *Probability 1*.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend Kallenberg's textbook https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387953137 which covers the central limit theorem but not the rate of convergence. For the latter, see chapter 3 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html

Comment: I glanced at the index, and didn't see any mention of Berry-Esseen.  Do you know if it's in there?

Comment: @Yly Good catch, it is not in there. Updated my answer.